# Add $ between two characters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to add a $ between a "A1notation result" , it returns the possition of today´s date in an array of dates (row)

```
So I have a row (A1:AA1) with dates and I want to find today´s date to insert a formula
```

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DB");
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'GMT-5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var ranges = sheet.createTextFinder(date).findAll().map(r => r.getA1Notation());
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).activate();  
  Logger.log(ranges)


This will show where today´s date is found and log [T1](for example). I am using it to insert a formula and copyTo the destination in the same column to getLastRow(), but when used it changes the value to T2, T3 and so on instead of keeping the value in T1, so im trying to change it to $T$1 to keep it in the exact same cell and not moving downwards. Does this meake sense? Thanks in advanced
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and `I need to add a $ between a "A1notation result" , it returns the possition of today´s date in an array of dates (row)`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Can you share more details on the expected result and sharing a dummy sheet with an example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an option to anchor the cell automatically, surely with some string manipulation. I suggest you put in your formula `INDIRECT("T1")` and it won't move